# Bluetooth version difference between Chip and Linux Kernel

Tags: bluetooth

The Bluetooth dongle(with CSR chip) we have can support BT version 4.0, but the Linux Kernel(2.6.23) running on the host is compatible with only BT version 2.x, will the dongle also be operating at BT ver 2.x?

Can someone please clarify.